# Default parameter must be compile-time constant in test class

Tags: c#

I have a test class that I want to be able to pass an optional class to. In my test I have a customer class defined in the test

```
public class Customer
{
  public string id { get; set; }
  public string firstName { get; set; }
  ...
}
```

I also initialize an instance of this when the test class loads

```
public class TestClass
{
  public static string APIKEY = "myapikey";

  Customer dummyCustomer = new Customer() { ...};
```

This has been working fine in my tests, so I can do

```
[TestMethod]
public void IsAPIActive()
{ ...
  var response = _service.GetResponse(dummyCustomer)
```

but now I want to be able to call one test from another and optionally pass the customer to that class

```
[TestMethod]
public int CanCreateCustomer(Customer customer = dummyCustomer)
{ ....
  return response.Customer.CustomerId;
```

In order that the existing test will pick up the default dummy customer but that some of my other tests can pass a different customer object to it.

When I have added this default customer though I just get a message that:

```
Default parameter value for 'customer' must be a compile-time constant.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, ask your self what do you want to **achieve** with the test? Is it already **tested**?

Then if a test is dependent on other tests then you have done something wrong, so think again. A test should be **isolated** to its own context and **not** dependent on other tests.

Though, if you have a code snippet that is the same for the two tests then you should extract that to it's own function that the both tests can call. But have in mind a **good** test only test **one** thing.

Comment: it's a payment provider integration. There are a number of calls that can be made. 
https://developer.optimalpayments.com/en/documentation/customer-vault-api/getting-started/
The first I wanted to do was an isolated test of creating a customer but then I wanted to make a different customer in order to test the next operation of adding an address to a profile. SO it wasn't to re-run the test as such but to create another customer. I take your point though, perhaps I should just create a separate call to the API rather than run through the create profile test again.

Comment: That's absolutely the preferred way of doing it, extract that part to it's own function and then call it from both tests. But I think it's unnecessary to test the API, if it's not just integration tests (the responsibility to test the API has the supplier). If you trying to write unit test, I suggest you to mock the API with Moq or other frameworks. Then you don't need to create a new customer for each test run. Then you just verify that you calling the API with the correct data.